# How to make a better image from two bad ones?

Tags: image, colors, graphics2d

Recently, I got myself involved into a little self-challenge project that can prove or disprove a scientific theory. For that I need to find a way to improve quality of an image given a set of it's (very) imperfect replicas.

Here, I have two (or more) really pixelated bad b&w images of the same thing. Images are of the same size and same lighting. They only differ in imperfections.

Is there an algorithm to merge the two to increase the picture quality?

That is, of course, using a programming language.

[image]
[image]

Here you can (or can you?) recognize two really bad reproductions of [Malevich "Black Circle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Circle) to illustrate my example.

Comment: Are you planning to share them with us?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure, the images can be any, but here are the two examples.